# Hibernate search and extended context transactions on Singleton Bean

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly-8, hibernate-search

I am using the following technologies: Wildfly 8.1.0 server and Hibernate-search.  Hibernate search requires an EntityManager with extended context transactions.  Only `@Stateful` EJBs support that kind of transactions, but at the same time I need the EJB to not be `@Stateful` but `@Singleton`, because at construction time of the EJB I am indexing the content of a database into memory.

How can I solve the contradiction? I have tried to make the @EJB `@Stateful`, but then I never stop indexing the database because it creates too many of them. I have tried to make it `@Singleton`, but then I run into transaction exceptions.  How can I make it a `@Stateful` bean and still limit the number of them that are created?  My standalone.xml config file is the standard one that comes with the download of Wildfly plus the addition of the datasource that I am using.  I am using managed transactions.

**EDIT adding the code to the question**

**Option 1: Singleton**

The problem with this option is that Singleton EJBs with managed transactions are not supposed to have entity managers with PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED.

```
@LocalBean
@Singleton
@Startup
public class LuceneBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MemberOfferPersistence",
         type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private FullTextEntityManager searchEM;



    public LuceneSetupBean(){

    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void populateIndex() throws Exception{
        this.searchEM =      Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
        searchEM.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    }

    //Other method calls that return query results.
}
```

**OPTION 2: Stateful bean**

The problem with this one is that Wildfly will create a new Lucene Bean each time I make a REST call to a service that uses the LuceneBean, which will fire the PostConstruct method reindexing from the database.

```
@LocalBean
@Stateful
public class LuceneBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MemberOfferPersistence",
         type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private FullTextEntityManager searchEM;

    public LuceneSetupBean(){

    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void populateIndex() throws Exception{
        this.searchEM =      Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
        searchEM.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    }

    //Other method calls that return query results.
}
```

Comment: Hi, one of the Hibernate contributors here. I didn't expect Hibernate Search to require "that kind of transactions" within an EJB. Could you post on the forums and share some more details, like the full stracktrace or error if any? I'd consider this a bug.

Comment: Could you post the code and the stacktraces?

Comment: @Sanne: I have added the code. I will post the stack trace later. I found a solution for it, so to get the stack trace I need to run my older code.